# How to use savepoints in SQLite3 in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite, rollback

I'm working on an iOS app that has a rather large sqlite database that gets at least once a day and I'd like to use savepoints to restore it if something happens while the transactions are running.

The statements I've been running are the following:

```
const char *sqlSetSavePoint = @"savepoint updateSavepoint";

const char *sqlRollback = @"Rollback transaction to savepoint updateSavepoint";
```

I have obviously omitted a lot of code that actually runs these statements, but since I'm running the same method for other statements and they work fine I have confidence that the problem isn't there. I'm setting the savepoint before running my insert transactions (inserting up to 200 thousand lines) and then if something throws an exception or an error I try to do a rollback.

My questions is; are these rollback statements correct (and I'm just doing something wrong) or is there some other way of using savepoints in sqlite3 in iOS?

EDIT: Just for clarification, I'm trying to set a savepoint before then running a number of transactions and if any of them, or a data fetch from the server, fail I want to do a total rollback to the savepoint. It is simply like this:

```
"savepoint updateSavepoint"
    ->FetchDatafromServer()
          -> "Begin exclusive transaction"
               //sqlite3_bind functions
          -> "Commit transaction"
    ->FetchDatafromServer()
          -> "Begin exclusive transaction"
               //sqlite3_bind functions
          -> "Commit transaction"
    ->FetchDatafromServer()
          -> "Begin exclusive transaction"
               //sqlite3_bind functions
          -> "Commit transaction"
    ->FetchDatafromServer()
          -> "Begin exclusive transaction"
              !!Failure!!
"Rollback transaction to savepoint updateSavepoint"
```

Comment: Just so you know you are using an `NSString` literal to create an `NSString` to get an UTF-8 string when all you need to do is `const char *sqlSetSavePoint = "savepoint updateSavepoint";`.

Comment: Ha, right you are. Guess I need more coffee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use savepoints inside a transaction or inside other savepoints, but you [cannot use transactions inside a savepoint](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_savepoint.html).

Replace your inner transactions with savepoints.

Comment: Well I am using transactions to do the inserts, but I'm doing it in a divide and conquer kind of way. Due to the large amount of data I'm only fetching data for one table at a time, inserting it using transactions and then fetching next table. 
I'm setting a savepoint before starting all this, and if anything brakes I want to roll back everything. But that isn't happening :/

Comment: After spending the whole day redoing a large chunk of my database transactions and figuring out how to best do this, I finally have it working just the way I wanted. Sincerely thank you for the help :)